# Prevent DBLookupComboBox from moving ADOTable cursor

Tags: delphi, ado

How to prevent DBLookupComboBox from moving a (record) cursor in underlying data set? I have set the ListSource and KeyField properties. I want it only to list the records and not move the cursor in underlying table. I am using Delphi XE2.

Comment: do you mean the dataset which holds the list of possible values? AFAIK, that is not possible.

Comment: @GuillemVicens Yes, that's the one. Please turn your comment into an answer and I will accept it. BTW what would be a workaround for this? StringList?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to prevent the `DBLookupCombobox` from moving the cursor in the underlying dataset. It needs to move along the records it lists to retrieve the value to be assigned to the *main dataset field*.

The usual approach is to have an *auxiliar dataset* that only holds the values you need for the `DBLookupCombobox`. This dataset would not be connected to any other object, including other datasets and visual components. This way you will have no problem with its cursor moving.